# init_declarator is a non-unique reference Antlr?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, dsl, antlr3

I am starting my symbol table, still new to it but facing some errors given by antlr in reference to my init_declarator rule. Any tips please

```
declaration
    : declaration_specifiers init_declarator_list? SEMICOLON! {currentScope.defineVariable($init_declarator_list.name,$declaration_specifier.type);} 
    ; 


declaration_specifiers returns [Symbol type]
    :   ( type_specifier{$type = $type_specifier.type;} |type_qualifier)+
    ;

init_declarator_list returns [Symbol name] 
    : init_declarator (COMMA init_declarator)*{$name = $init_declarator.name;} -> ^(INIT_DECLARATOR_LIST init_declarator+)
    ;

init_declarator returns [Symbol name]
    : declarator (ASSIGN^ initializer)?  {$name = $declarator.name;}
    ;

declarator returns [Symbol name]
    : pointer? direct_declarator{$name = $direct_declarator.text;}
    | pointer
    ;

direct_declarator returns [Symbol name]
    :   (   IDENTIFIER| LPAREN! declarator RPAREN!   ) 
        declarator_suffix* {$name = $IDENTIFIER.text;}
    ;   
type_specifier returns [Symbol type] : (CONST^)? (VOID{return VoidType;} | CHAR {return CharType;}| INT{return IntType;} | FLOAT{return FloatType;} );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has to do with the following rule:

```
init_declarator_list returns [Symbol name] 
    : init_declarator (COMMA init_declarator)*{$name = $init_declarator.name;} -> ^(INIT_DECLARATOR_LIST init_declarator+)
    ;
```

In your action, `$init_declarator.name` could be referring to either the first or the second reference to `init_declarator` in the rule. Try labeling the one you want to use. For example, in the following rule I've labeled both references with `x=`, so the action `$x.name` will refer to whatever the last `init_declarator` was.

```
init_declarator_list returns [Symbol name] 
    : x=init_declarator (COMMA x=init_declarator)*{$name = $x.name;} -> ^(INIT_DECLARATOR_LIST init_declarator+)
    ;
```

Comment: This is so weird - ANTLR is fine with using the same name "x" in both cases and when you use $x it picks up the *last* one before the rule. So why doesn't it just do exactly the same thing with the name "init_declarator", allowing you to access the last one? This restriction is especially annoying when you have code in the middle of rules, and obviously referring to the previous object of the given name.